# Dynamic properties for Angular controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically load a controller based on different values and want to know what's the practical way in doing so? See below.

I'm trying to retrieve the **data-post-id** attribute's value within the controller that it is within.

Suppose I have multiple **CommentsController** div on the same, page and each of them is associated with a different **data-post-id**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**JS**

```
app.controller("CommentsController", function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.comments = [];
   $scope.load = function() {
      $http.get("https://myapi.com/comments.json", [post_id: post_id])
          .success(function(data) {
              $scope.comments = data;
          });
   };
   // Load the data
   $scope.load();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="CommentsController as comments" data-post-id="30">
   <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
      {{ comment.body }} - {{ comment.author }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you creating a hybrid, using server-side to generate the post id?  Normally you'd have an ng-repeat over the posts and the id would already be on your scope.  Better would be to create a durective with the comment template in it or in a script tag and it can access that attribute and put it on the scope as well as set the controller.

Comment: Im confused, why do you need to load more than one controller? And also its widely considered to be a 'best practice' to put your $http requests in factories/services rather than directly in your controllers.

Comment: if u want to access data-post-id in the controller, why not bind it with some module, u can set that value in ng-init="post-id=30" data-post-id="{{post-id}}"

Comment: @Pytth, controllers are bind to scopes and a typical application can have multiple controllers. Scopes can be inherited from another or independent from each other. However, services are singleton objects and don't bind to any scope. Just refer the official documentation for more information - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0):

This could take place in your angular.module('app').config(function(){

You can have an array of controller types, i.e. `var yourCtlrTypes = ['comments','posts','users']` and then use Angular's [Controller Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider) inside of a loop through that array. Your loop would create a controller for each name in the array and each controller could also have special naming for $scopes and variables according to the array.. i.e. images[x] = {} where x is the current item from the looped array.

});

Let me know if this makes sense or i can make a demo.